# Using jackson to map an unnamed array

Tags: java, json, twitter, jackson

Hitting the [twitter friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids) API endpoint without a cursor specified will return this JSON response:

`["243439460","13334762", "14654522"]`

however when specifying a cursor you get the documented format:

`{"next_cursor":0,"previous_cursor":0,"ids":["243439460","13334762","14654522"]}`

Using Jackson to deserialise the second response is easy using

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FriendIds {
private List<String> ids;

public List<String> getIds() { return ids; }

public void setIds(List<String> ids) { this.ids = ids; }
}
```

and

`FriendIds friendIds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr, FriendIds.class);`

However I haven't found a similar way to deserialise the first response to `FriendIds` using Jackson. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: first response is not JSON - it's just an array

Comment: @IgorDymov Yeah, it is. I initially thought that, but ever validator I threw it at accepted it. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It is valid JSON, no problem, but as an array it needs to be mapped to an array or collection....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just mapping them to id list first like:

```
List<String> ids = mapper.readValue(json, List.class); // works because String happens to be 'natural' type for JSON Strings
```

and then just construct wrapper object?

There is no real way for Jackson to know that a JSON array was to be used to construct a POJO where one of the fields is to contain contents of the list, except by writing a custom deserializer.
That is a possibility if you want to do it; and that could in fact support both cases. But needs some thinking, to use one method (default POJO deser) for JSON Objects, another for JSON arrays.
So it might just be easiest to do it outside of Jackson.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps.  You can do this using Spring RestTemplate.getForObject and Jackson annotations.

This is the class for the Twitter Response:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class TwitterResponse {
  private List<TwitterId> ids;

  @JsonCreator
  public TwitterResponse(List<TwitterId> ids) {
    this.ids = ids;
  }

  public List<TwitterId> getIds() {
    return ids;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TwitterResponse [ids=" + ids + "]";
  }

}
```

This is the TwitterId class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class TwitterId {

  private String twitterId;

  public TwitterId(String twitterId) {
    this.twitterId = twitterId;
  }

  public String getTwitterId() {
    return twitterId;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TwitterId [twitterId=" + twitterId + "]";
  }

}
```

And a simple unit test showing it works.  I just created a simple controller that returns your data above, and I'm testing it using RestTemplate

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class ControllerTest {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerTest.class);
@Test
  public void testTwitter() {
    try {
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

      TwitterResponse twitterResponse =
          restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/twitter",
              TwitterResponse.class);

      log.debug("twitterResponse = {}", twitterResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

And the console showing test result:

```
19:57:42.506 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://localhost:8080/twitter"
19:57:42.545 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
19:57:42.558 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8080/twitter" resulted in 200 (OK)
19:57:42.559 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading [class org.porthos.simple.TwitterResponse] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4b5a5ed1]
19:57:42.572 [main] DEBUG org.porthos.simple.ControllerTest - twitterResponse = TwitterResponse [ids=[TwitterId [twitterId=243439460], TwitterId [twitterId=13334762], TwitterId [twitterId=14654522]]]
```